# How to have granular control of 2nd level cache when using polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, many-to-one

I have ~40 classes, and they all implement an interface IEntity.

Of the ~40 classes, many use a "Many-To-One" mapping to an IEntity property.  An example of this could be:

```
"IEntity.cs"
public interface IEntity
{
   Guid ID
   ...Other properties (~7 of them)
}

"Item.cs"
public class Item : IEntity
{

   Public Guid ID {get;set;}
   ...Other IEntity Properties

   Public IEntity Owner {get;set;}  

}
```

I believe to use NHibernate to map the Owner property on Item, I will need to use one of NHibernate's inheritance mappings using IEntity as a base.

The issue is that configuration of the 2nd level cache is tied to a class definition, not to the subclasses.  I would have to turn on caching on all ~40 classes in my model at one time, and I wouldn't be able to just cache the classes I want, such as categories.

Does anyone know how I can map an entity that has a property that is the type of an abstract entity without losing the ability to make 2nd level cache choices?

Comment: I can't offer a bounty, but if you post a good answer, I will go through and look at some of your previous answers on other questions to see if they deserve an upvote as well.

Comment: A bounty may still be the right answer.  One user going back and upvoting a bunch of other posts will likely trigger the spam protection and all the rep will be lost a day later.

Comment: This sounds like you want an <any> mapping rather than a <many-to-one> see http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any

Comment: @insta didn't know about the spam filter.  Thanks.

Comment: Chris can let me know if the spam filter takes away some of his points tomorrow =) The any mapping was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, I'm not sure I really get the idea of defining properties' type as `IEntity`- are you sure it's okay for `Item` to be the owner of another item? is it okay for an `Employee` to be the owner of an item?
If the answer is yes, and that's the business logic of your system, then there's nothing to do about this.
Otherwise- you may find it helpful to define an `IOwner` or even a `OwnerBase` base class to help with that distinction.
This may also be helpful with ditinguishing which classes to cache and which not to.

And now to the caching question:

the definition of 2nd level cache needs to occur in two places:
1. The class's mapping
2. The association mapping

in your case, I believe you would indeed have to turn on 2nd level cache for all the `IEntity` classes. **But** if you only turn on the caching for *specific* associations, then only those associations would be cached.
(an exception to this is using `Get<T>()` or `Load<T>()` methods, which would also cause your objects to be cached. If I'm not mistaken, you can tell nHib *not* to use the cache for specific queries)

Comment: Yes, the Item can be owned by any other type of entity, or at least a subset of them.  I ended up using an Any mapping instead.